# Problemas com parse de JSON no AngularJS

Tags: html, json, angularjs

Tenho um controller que retorna um objeto JSON no seguinte formato :

```
[
  {"idCliente":1,
   "nomeFantasia":"Flores",
   "razaoSocial":"Transportes Flores Ltda.",
   "contatosClientes": 
   [ {"idContatoCliente":1,
      "dddCelular":21,
      "email":"ljames@cavaliers.com"},
     {"idContatoCliente":2,
      "dddCelular":21,
      "email":"teste@teste.com"}
   ]
  }
]
```

E tenho um template que tenta formatar os dados acima da seguinte forma :

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes | filter:searchText">
   <td>{{cliente.idCliente}}</td>
   <td>{{cliente.razaoSocial}}</td>
   <td>{{cliente.nomeFantasia}}</td>
   <td>{{cliente.contatosClientes.email}}</td>
   <td>
   <div class="right floated ui green icon buttons">
       <div class="ui button">Editar</i></div>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

O problema é que as chaves mais altas (`idCliente`, `razaoSocial`, etc) eu consigo acessar com a sintaxe `objeto.chave`, mas as chaves nos *arrays* aninhados (`contatosClientes`) eu não consigo acessar da mesma forma (`cliente.contatosClientes.email`).

Já tentei de tudo e estou até pensando em alterar a minha API, mas alguém sabe como fazer isso no AngularJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antonio você já tentou acessar os itens novamente em um ng-repeat? por exemplo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes | filter:searchText">
<td>{{cliente.idCliente}}</td>
<td>{{cliente.razaoSocial}}</td>
<td>{{cliente.nomeFantasia}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="contato in cliente.contatosClientes>{{contato.email}}</td>
<td>
<div class="right floated ui green icon buttons">
   <div class="ui button">Editar</i></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Estava com o mesmo problema e aqui consegui resolver assim

Comment: Wendel, alterei aqui como você sugeriu mas não funcionou.

Comment: @AntonioBelloni o exemplo do Wendel acima faltou apenas um detalhe para funcionar. Ao invés de `<td ng-repeat="contato in cliente>{{contato.email}}</td>` utilize `<td ng-repeat="contato in cliente.contatosClientes>{{contato.email}}</td>`

Comment: @ThiagoDorneles Obrigado, nem tinha percebido esse detalhe

Comment: funcionou !!! Obrigado pela ajuda.